# Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid$z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=2y$

Tags: multiple-integral

Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and the plane $z=2y$ using the integral $$\iiint dxdzdy$$ without changing the order of integral.

What should be the limits of integral if the order is to be kept the same?
also find the volume of the solid enclosed by the two surfaces.